# searching a multiple line pattern using grep regex

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I am relatively new to linux I want to search a pattern in a file which starts with "Leonard is" and ends on "champion"

Also this pattern might be placed in multiple lines

the input file(input.txt) may look like:

```
1 rabbit eats carrot Leonard is a champion 
2 loin is the king of 
3 jungle Leonard is a 
4 Champion 
5 Leonard is An exemplary 
6 Champion
```

i would want to have all the occurrences of my pattern ignoring all the other characters other than the pattern in the output file:

```
1 Leonard is a champion
3 Leonard is a
4 Champion
5 Leonard is An exemplary
6 Champion
```

i have been very close with the following command:

```
cat input.txt | grep -ioE "Leonard.*Champion$"
```

as this command only returns

```
1 Leonard is a champion
```

ignoring all the patterns occurring in multiple line

if any other approach of searching other than grep is useful kindly let me know Thanks!!

Comment: Great job with reformatting! :)

Comment: Try `grep -iPoz "(?m)Leonard.*?Champion$"` (if you are using a GNU `grep`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -l -0777 -e 'print for <> =~ /(.*Leonard(?s:.*?)[Cc]hampion.*)/g' -- input.txt
```

- `-l` adds newlines to prints
- `-0777` reads the whole file instead of processing it line by line
- the diamond operator `<>` reads the input
- `.*?` is like `.*`, i.e. it matches anything, but the `?` means the shortest possible match is enough. That prevents the regex from matching everything between the first Leonard and last Champion.
- `.` in a regex doesn't match a newline normally, but it does with the `s` modifier. `(?s:.*?)` localizes the changed behaviour, so other dots still don't match newlines.

Comment: your command results all the text for those lines containg the pattern
Mean while I want to get only the Leonard is a champion part ignoring  all the text before and after it other than that i also want a flag ignoring all the case as LEONARD could LeOnard as well same goes for CHAMPION Thanks!!!

Comment: @HammadAhmed: Use the `/i` modifier to match in a case ignoring way. To omit the line starts and ends, just remove the `.*` from the beginning and end of the regex.

Comment: perl -l -0777 -e 'print for <> =~ /(Leonard(?s:.*?)[Cc]hampion)/gi' -- input.txt
Works well!!! thanks!

Comment: @HammadAhmed: You can replace `[Cc]` by `c` as `/i` makes it match both `C` and `c`.

Comment: yes i know this was overlooked by mistake any ways Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `\s` which stands for whitespace. `+` stands for one or more

Pattern: `Leonard is a\s+Champion`

See: https://regex101.com/r/qiNXhf/1

I use this tool with 0 knowledge of regex in my mind, and it helps me a lot. See the notes on the right bottom, where all these signs are explained.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ".*" is referenced as "any character **except new line**", therefore, what you're trying to achieve with .* is not possible, I suggest using \s with an addition of * or + as well (as suggested above), but need to find out how to implement it with the "grep" reg expression. There are also nice tools for regex testing - https://regexr.com/ for example.